Does $\Lambda^0 \rightarrow p^+ + \pi^-$ reaction involve strong or weak force?
Since $\Lambda^0$ has strangeness equal to +1, a proton has strangeness equal to 0, and a pion has strangeness equal to 0, can I therefore conclude that  the reaction
$$\Lambda^0 \rightarrow p^+  +  \pi^-$$
must go via the weak force?
I ask this because of something similar I read in [1], which reads,

"Since both pions have a strangeness of 0, this violates conservation of strangeness, meaning the reaction must go via the weak force [1]."

Bibliography
[1] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strangeness

Indeed, all strangeness-changing decays are weak. First fact you learn about strangeness.

Yes, you are correct.
At the quark level, the $\Lambda^0$ is one up, one down, and one strange quark (thus it has strangeness). The proton is two ups and one down, and the $\pi^-$ pion is one antiup and one down.
Before the decay there is an up, a down, and a strange, and after there are two ups, one antiup, and two downs. So,
$$uds\rightarrow ud(u\overline{u}d)    \tag{1}.$$
Note that if you were to "cancel" the antiup with another up by particle-antiparticle production and annihilation can happen, which is not justified by the physics much but nonetheless convenient for predictive purposes, then you would get an an up and two downs after the decay. In other words
$$
 ud(u\overline{u}d)  = ud(u\overline{u})d   \rightarrow u dd  . \tag{2}$$
This heuristically shows that there  needs to be a weak "flavor-changing" interaction to convert a strange quark into a down quark and there also needs to exist enough energy in  the reagents  to produce the up-antiup pair.
Since the strange quark is unstable, the conversion in Equation 1 happens spontaneously due to the weak interaction that causes the lambda baryon to decay. The energy released (plus the energy difference between the $\Lambda^0$ and the $p^++\pi^-$ binding energies, plus any other energy that the lambda baryon has for any reason) go into the pair production that leads to the extra up and antiup.
At that point, the two ups and a down hadronize into a proton and antiup and down go off as a pi meson. In other words,
$$  ud(u\overline{u}d) \rightarrow  uud +  \overline{u}d   \rightarrow p^+ + \pi^- \tag{3}.$$
Note that it is impossible for the decay (see Equation 1) to occur without the weak force, because without the weak interaction the strange quark can't change flavors to become a down quark. The strong force isn't the cause; the strong force might contribute binding energy to the lambda baryon/proton to make the decay more likely, but it doesn't cause the interaction.

Were the $u$ and $\overline{u}$ to annihilate (see Equation 2 in your answer),  is there anything released, created, destroyed? Perhaps a photon is emitted?

With respect to the weak interaction that causes the lambda baryon to decay, what mediates the weak interaction? Is it perhaps a $W^+$,  a $W^-$, or a  $Z^0$?

I understand that "when chemical reactions occur, the atoms are rearranged and the reaction is accompanied by an energy change as new products are generated. [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chemical_reaction]".  Would you classify the reaction in Eq. 1 as exothermic, in which heat is produced? The strange quark has rest energy of 93.5 J; the down quark has rest energy of 4.7 J; and the up quark and anti-up quark have energies of 2.16 J [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Model]. Thus,  the reagents have considerably more energy than the products, heat should be released in the reaction.

With respect to the conversion from $s$ to $u\overline{u}d$, are there any color constraints on the quarks that comprise the product?


Quark-antiquark annihilation would indeed produce two photons (to conserve momentum) with each energy equal to half the total energy of the system beforehand, but that is less frequently observed than hadronization. 2. You can determine which weak boson caused the flavor change by knowing that the initial charge of the system $R$ and the final charge of the system $P+[W\text{ or }Z]$ have to be equal. 3. Define "exothermic". In chemistry, exothermicity makes sense because temperature is different from mass/energy; here ... (contd)


(contd) ... mass-energy and kinetic energy (temperature) are considered together, and there is exactly as much energy after the decay as before the decay. 4. Color charge isn't very well defined for free quarks, since the charge is confined to within hadrons. For one, the down quark that the strange quark decays into would probably retain its existing color charge since the W/Z bosons have no color charge and it must be conserved; whatever color charge the brand-new up and antiup have, they must cancel. I would recommend posting these new (very interesting) questions for more info.

Lastly, addressing your explanation as to the exothermicity of the reaction, the rest energy lost by the lambda baryon when it decays is converted to the kinetic energy of the products. This is why radioactive isotopes can emit dangerously-energetic radiation; as the nucleons lose mass-energy, it's converted into kinetic energy of the radiated particles. The total energy is exactly the same before and after.
